# 'Server refused our key' upon attempted connection to Windows Server

Tags: ssh, putty, openssh, authentication, ssh-keys

I'm attempting to use PuTTY to securely connect my remote desktop from my laptop to my desktop computer, and so far I have been successful in tunneling through the proper ports WITHOUT A KEY, just by using my username and password. These are both Windows machines, running Windows 10.

I generated a key using PuTTYGen, and each time I would copy and paste the `public key` into `C:\Users\Chris\.ssh\authorized_keys` (on the server) like so:

```
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABJQAAAQBl8kTxv8cxW5tSvNjId+qrype1ZA+zEO3Qag+BHhlMvvtrx/faZp8XMXbSqulZVqXNFnN0ADAaAv2hMltP+rft4R8X9qaJSIlYdPo8F3BmV5G2mu+AQKnOrGooLfwc2oa4qOfHJMqzciFqVVTAOjo3BQ3ZtZnN23os1WfiRCcwlNZgrRlgpUPkA/CgaWTDnlDpxvNZp3fVia8pDvLlqVIIn+Fu7UEJi/pNDUiexrky7nR0JzIL3ZAPAu6U26WLJA7fYw7nlySzz/BuxiPyIzeRT+qiHQuwf2yOkCXNIeQQjgLsbw0eS67TWC7pa6NbLa0KqmgDChdSNsSB5aKTMh3T rsa-key-20190410
```

Then, on the client, I select the private key file in `Settings > Connection > SSH > Auth > Private key file for Authentication > C:\Users\Chris\Desktop\SSH-KEY\key1.ppk`

I have double and triple checked: the public key that I pasted into `authorized_keys` corresponds to the private key that is loaded into PuTTY.

When I attempt to connect the session, I get this error:

```
Using username "Chris".
Server refused our key
Chris@my.pub.lic.ip's password:
```

I am able to find no further documentation or error codes.

There is no log file present, but when I enabled logging manually and opened it up after connection, this was present in the file for the client:

```
Using username "Chris".
Server refused our key
Chris@my.pub.lic.ip's password:
```

I have tried both using `Chris` and `chris`, in addition to generating and using key pairs generated from the server, and from the client.

I later found an additional log file for the server in `C:\ProgramData\ssh\logs\sshd.log`:

```
1184 2019-04-10 12:38:48.995 Server listening on :: port 22.
1184 2019-04-10 12:38:48.995 Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.
13568 2019-04-10 12:39:00.943 Authentication refused.
13568 2019-04-10 12:39:04.395 Connection closed by authenticating user chris my.pub.lic.ip port 54460 [preauth]
```

I've seen several suggestions about using `chmod`, and checking `/var/log/secure`, both of which are useless to me as they are linux commands and directories, and both of these machines are Windows.

I'll admit: I've kind of been losing my marbles over this. I'm doing everything that every tutorial anywhere suggests, and nothing is working.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue. In short, this resulted from two separate "misconfigurations" from my side.

1. You need to use the "administrators_authorized_keys" in the case of an admin user.
2. The authorized_keys file needs to be of specific permissions to be used.

Make sure to create the file:

```
%PROGRAMDATA%\ssh\administrators_authorized_keys
```

Insert your SSH public key into it, and then make sure it has the right permissions by running the following command in powershell:

```
icacls.exe "C:\ProgramData\ssh\administrators_authorized_keys" /inheritance:r /grant "Administrators:F" /grant "SYSTEM:F"
```

This seems to have solved the problem for me. Assuming your user isn't an admin user, try only the permission part on your authorized_keys file. Perhaps it will solve it.

This solution is based on https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_keymanagement under the "Administrative User" part

Answer (score 6):

I think I'm facing the same problem...
Any luck since then? Have you found the reason/solution?

**EDIT:**

OK, I found the cause of the issue on my side... It could be the same for you too, Chris, if you're SSH'ing with an administrator account:

Actually, a comment in this post pointed out to the issue:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20864224/putty-getting-server-refused-our-key-error

*"the main fact that as an Administrator there is a bug that only looks in the administrators_authorized_keys file and not the expected Users .ssh folder for authorized_keys (everybody's point of grief running sshd on Windows)"*

**Solution:**

At the end / bottom of the sshd_config file that's in %programdata%\ssh you need to comment out (or remove) the last two lines:

```
Match Group Administrators
    AuthorizedKeysFile __PROGRAMDATA__/ssh/administrators_authorized_keys
```

The SSH server needs to be restarted to take it into account.

Another (maybe more secure) way would be to create such "administrators_authorized_keys" file under %programdata%\ssh and add the clients' public keys in there in those are indeed admin users.

Comment: Unfortunately no :/ I just ended up using KiTTY and just storing a password in there.

Comment: Sorry Ramhound, I'm new to StackExchange... You can see I was encouraging Chris to share a solution in case he had one.

Comment: Anyway, I fixed the problem on my side and updated my answer with it. This should do.

Comment: Thanks for providing the link - it contains more steps necessary to get it working.

Comment: Your solution works for me on Win 7. Thx!

Answer (score 1):

```
Match Group Administrators
AuthorizedKeysFile __PROGRAMDATA__/ssh/administrators_authorized_keys
```

Keep in Mind, that 'Administrators' is the localized name of the Adminstrator-Group! In German, for example,  you have to change it in

```
Match Group administratoren
   AuthorizedKeysFile __PROGRAMDATA__/ssh/administrators_authorized_keys
```

Comment: Welcome to SU.  Please bear in mind that this site is not run like a forum. Answers are expected to be unique.